# Convert to animated gif, transparency does not re-emerge

Tags: terminal, type-conversion, transparency, animated-gif

I am making an animated gif.

This gif is 50 frames or so and it contains quite some transparency.

The problem is that when transparency is to reemerge in the gif, it doesn't and instead continues to display whatever color was at that given pixel before the transparency was to appear.

How can i make the animated gif showing transparency when the given pixel becomes transparent?

Below is the terminal command i use to create this flawed gif.

```
convert -delay 5 -loop 0 pics/1.gif pics/2.gif animation.gif'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You apply the 'dispose background' option.
see: http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/anim_basics/